# How to append number to p:selectOneMenu id

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have the following code

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="dynamicId_#{loopStatus.index}" .....

`loopStatus` comes from `<p:dataGrid  varStatus="loopStatus".....`
```

but when the page is rendered i see the the id of `<p:selectOneMenu` becomes like the following  `dynamicId_` only and it does not append the number that comes from `loopStatus.index` could some one help me to fix this issue?.

Comment: The behaviour you see cannot be determined by the code you posted. I don't see anything that generates/produces a `lootStatus.index` so that would (in production) mean it is empty. [mcve] please (most likely you use a ui:repeat where a c:foreach would be appropriate, ASSUMING you actually really 100% need the id to be different since in a ui:repeat it is already made different with an index)

Comment: And tried with other PF components or a `h:selectOneMenu`? Won't work either. Duplicte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: @Kukeltje hope the edit i made helps you to understand from where loopStatus[have corrected so that it makes sense] comes from.

Comment: If you use a dataGrid, there already is an index in the client-side id...like in a ui:repeat...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: You can't use ids like that. See the linked post about JSTL in JSF2 for more information.